# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - Can't connect redux with wrapper function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

for Auth Guard in my routing function, I wrapped my component with a HOC function. Something like this

`<Route path="/profile" component={withAuth(UserProfileScreen)} />`

So I tried to validate authentication in wrapper function for that I need to connect redux with the wrapper function. So I'm trying like this.

```
function withAuth(ComponentToProtect) {
    return class extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                loading: true,
                redirect: false,
            };
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            // logic to check signin
          this.props.manageUserLogin(true)
        }

        render() {
            const { loading, redirect } = this.state;
            if (loading) {
                return null;
            }
            if (redirect) {
                 return <Redirect to="/" />;
            }
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <ComponentToProtect {...this.props} />
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
    };
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isUserLoggedIn: state.authR.isUserLoggedIn,\
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        manageUserLogin: (action) =>
            dispatch(
                actionCreators.manageUserLogin(action)
            ),
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withAuth);`
```

When I connect redux with wrapper function, I'm getting like `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` error.

Comment: have you tried named export?

Comment: yeah, same error. But this error is something like if I connect with redux it made as an object, but the wrapper function export should be another component. that's why I'm getting this error

Comment: have you tried using `compose`? can't think of anything else

Comment: not yet Can u help u with that,

Comment: try the answer, code was too long for comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const withAuthHoc = compose(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps), withAuth);

export default withAuthHoc;
```

Comment: Just now I tried with this reference, it can solved my issues.https://medium.com/practo-engineering/connected-higher-order-component-hoc-93ee63c91526

Comment: Thanks Red Baron, this is really help me